# Table relation and query Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, database, entity-framework, ado.net, entity-framework-5

- Parent table `AspNetUser` -> child table `Ad`
- Parent table `Ad` -> child table `Mobile Ad`
- Parent table `Ad` -> child table `AdsLocation` (multiple locations against one ad)
- Parent table `City` -> child table `PopularPlace`

Questions:

1. Should I have to add relation between `Mobile Ad` and `Mobile` ? (`Mobile` entity should not be deleted on deletion of `MobileAd` and there should not be repeated rows in `Mobile` table )
2. Should I have to add relation of `AdsLocation` with `City` and `PopularPlace` ?
3. Write a query to get ads on the basis of `companyName` (Mobile table) and should retrieve userName, title, price, companyName, modelName and multiple locations with cityName and popularPlaceName (in short retrieve a column from each table :) Method syntax should be preferred.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

1) Yes you should create a relation between mobile and mobile ad because mobile ad is referencing mobile id.

2) Yes you should create a relation between AdsLocation and City because AdsLocation is referencing city id.

3) Until the relation in part 1 is not formed, this query will not be possible. However, while trying to write the LINQ Query for this question, I realized there are some design issues with your database. For example, can the same Ad be posted by different companies? At the moment your design allows it. Your design also allows any user to post the ad for any company. In real world, only marketing team of company X should be able to create ads for company X. I think you should spend some more time reviewing this design!

Comment: Thanks but `Mobile` entity should not be deleted on deletion of `MobileAd` and there should not be repeated rows in `Mobile` table. So primary foreign relation is not suitable.

Comment: Why are you going for primary foreign relation? MobileAd has a simple foreign key to mobile. In the current design, I would imagine Ad and Mobile created before MobileAd is created.

Comment: yes Ad and Mobiles are created before MobileAd is created. What relation should I use?

Comment: If you are doing Database first, use Foreign Key constraint. If you are doing Code First, then you will need to share your models.

Comment: I am using Database first. `Foreign Key constraint defines a rule that constrains a foreign key to values that match only those values contained in a referenced unique key` I think applying constraint is the same as creating primary foreign relation.

Comment: It's not the same. You create a primary key only on mobile and you create a foreign key in the mobile ad table. When you delete a mobile ad, it won't delete a mobile. But when you delete a mobile, you can specify settings on your foreign key (on delete cascade) which will automatically delete a mobile ad.